# remove duplicata in multiline in javascript and keep single line

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

Whenever drag or change the zoom of google maps, the function callAjax is called.

When i want send my message ajax equest is exectued :

[multiline in var url http://screencloud.net/img/screenshots/9be42375b3978da687b944a376861c82.png](http://screencloud.net/img/screenshots/9be42375b3978da687b944a376861c82.png)

`null` and `http://localhost:8888/ptf/public/products/1/iWant` => is same variable `(urlIWant)`

the number of line is equal of number of times that we drag or change the zoom of google maps, this exemple is change three times (2 null + localhost)

Each times that we change of google maps `callAjax`is executed :

```
function callAjax(page){

// instancie la variable
var urlIWant = null;

/* Google maps */ 
var bds = map.getBounds();
var South_Lat = bds.getSouthWest().lat();
var South_Lng = bds.getSouthWest().lng();
var North_Lat = bds.getNorthEast().lat();
var North_Lng = bds.getNorthEast().lng();

dataQuery = 'SO_Lt='+South_Lat+'&SO_lg='+South_Lng+'&NE_lt='+North_Lat+'&NE_lg='+North_Lng+'&showUser='+showUser;


// Ajax request who return me the html who contain the products
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'search',
    data: dataQuery,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#loader').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#result').addClass('hidden');
    },
    success: handleResponse
});
```

When the user click on modal "I Want"

```
        $('.iWant').click(function(event) {

            // Stop the loading 
            event.preventDefault();
            // catch the url for Ajax Request
            urlIWant = $(this).attr('href');
            $('#iWantModal').modal('show');
        });
```

When the user click for to send his message

```
        $('#sendMessage').click(function(){

            // show the multiple line
            console.log(urlIWant);

            // call ajax (API)
            $.ajax({
                url: urlIWant,
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    messageSend: $('#messageSend').val(),
                    emailSend: $('#emailSend').val(),
                    name: $('#userName').text(),
                    userId: $('#userId').text()
                },
                beforeSend: function(request) {
                    return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("input[name='_token']").val());
                },
                success: function() {

                    // Close the modal
                    $('#iWantModal').modal('hide'); 

                    $("#messageSend").val('');
                },
                // When ajax request is complete (success or error)
                complete : function(){

                    urlIWant = null;
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

How to keep the end line `http://localhost:8888/ptf/public/products/1/iWant` ?
And why each times that callAjax is called incremente 'urlIWant' instead of replace

Thanks

Comment: Please clean up your question and remove any irrelevant code. Right now, it is impossible to tell what you are asking.

Comment: I'm sorry and Right now it's oki ?

Comment: No; we still can't tell what you're asking. What does this mean: "How to keep the end line http://localhost:8888/ptf/public/products/1/iWant?" What does this mean: "And why each times that callAjax is called incremente 'urlIWant' instead of replace?" You aren't incrementing `urlIWant` anywhere.

Comment: I don't understand why `urlIWant` contained multilines. yet `urlIWant = $(this).attr('href');` must ecrease the old content for new content. Here, it add line. Do you understand (I'm sorry for my English)?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. You need to explain (and give an example) of what you mean by "`urlIWant` contained multilines" ("multilines" doesn't have a real meaning in English).  And you need to explain and give an example for "yet `urlIWant = $(this).attr('href');` must ecrease the old content for new content." What do you mean by "must ecrease the old content for new content?"

Comment: When I change zoom of my google maps, `callAjax` is executed who call `$.ajax`, It return one html who contain my all products (search page). Each products to a button named 'Je veux' (http://screencloud.net/v/9ZoI), when i click this button, a modal appears (http://screencloud.net/v/gU6E). This button contain a link => `http://localhost:8888/ptf/public/products/1/iWant` and when i click on `envoyer` a ajax request is executed (last code in my question). It's ok But when i change again and again my google maps the `var urlIWant` is incremented one line `null` and i don't understand why

Comment: This just doesn't mean anything: "the var urlIWant is incremented one line null." You set `urlIWant = null;` when your AJAX call finishes. You never increment it, though (and you can't really increment a string, anyway).

Comment: The first two lines = http://screencloud.net/img/screenshots/9be42375b3978da687b944a376861c82.png is my var urlIWant in console.log. It contain 2 null (3 change zoom of google maps)

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't help. How did it get there? When did it get there? Where was this in the script above? Your question is still extremely unclear.

Comment: i resolved my problem : just add `.off('click')` in my `#sendMessage` => `$('#sendMessage').off('click').click(function()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem

Juste add `.off('clicks)` in my `$('#sendMessage')` =

```
         $('#sendMessage').off('click').click(function(){

            console.log(urlIWant);

            // fait l'appel ajax vers le controller de l'API
            $.ajax({
                url: urlIWant,
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    messageSend: $('#messageSend').val(),
                    emailSend: $('#emailSend').val(),
                    name: $('#userName').text(),
                    userId: $('#userId').text()
                },
                success: function() {
                    logDebug('success');
                    // Ferme le modal
                    $('#iWantModal').modal('hide');

                    /* supprime le contenu du textarea, pour ne pas garder l'ancien
                     * contenu ajouté, s'il y en avait un.
                     */
                    $("#messageSend").val('');
                }
            }
```